# API only returns one result from database call

Tags: sql, json, reactjs, api

The SQL database contains more than 40 rows of data to return but the API fetch only returns the first one. I have tested this with multiple tables and get the same result. I will attach all the necessary code but the code attached was working fine prior to merging branches with someone else's. From there, I cannot spot the problem. We are designing a GridView that displays multiple vinyl records pulled in from our database.

**the result from the localhost**

```
{"VinylID":1,"RecordLabel":"A&M Records","Genre":"Rock","Artist":"The Police","ProductID":1,"Name":"Dont Stand So Close To Me","VinylPrice":null}
```

**server.js**

```
// test
connection.query('SELECT * FROM VINYL', function (err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) {throw err}
  res.json(rows[0])
  console.log(rows[0])
  console.log(rows[0].ProductDescription)

})
connection.end()
})
```

**records.js**

```
   
  constructor(props) {
   console.log('constructor problem')
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: [] }
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/ShowDummyText')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(inData => this.setState({data: inData}));
  }

 render() {
   console.log('render problem')
    return (
       <div style={{ marginTop: "10%" }}>
          <Products products = {this.state.data} />
       </div>
    )
 }
}
export default Table
```

**products.js**

```
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
    <main className={classes.content}>
    <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <Grid container justify ="center" spacing={3}>
            {() => products.map((product) => (
                <Grid item key={product.id}xs ={3} sm={6} md={4}>
                    <Product product={product}/>
                </Grid>
            ))}
        </Grid>
    </main>
    )
}
export default Products
```

Comment: I don't think this is cause of issue, but you shouldn't call `this.setState` in the `constructor`. `fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/ShowDummyText')` should occur when the component mounts, call `fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/ShowDummyText')` in `componentDidMount` lifecycle method. When the fetch is complete and state is updated, do you see all the correct data there? What about the network request/response, does that have the correct data? Why complicate the `products` rendering by making it an anonymous function? You should be able to just `products.map(....` without a function.

Comment: @DrewReese None of it seems to make much change. I was under the impression that when it comes to mounting in react `Constructor()` works fine. Maybe the problem is the this.setState. As for the anonymous function, I continued to get a `products.map is not a function` error that would not go away until I added in a `() =>.` Again the table displayed perfectly fine before, I still don't know what the issue is

Comment: Well, it is "probably fine" because the fetch returns a Promise that is resolved later *after* the component has mounted. It is accidentally working. `products.map is not a function` means you mutated the `data` state into something other than an array. Can you share the actual JSON response you get? I.E. what is the value of `inData` when you are updating state? "It worked fine before" - do you not have a git history to see what changes have been applied from when it was working?